How to calculate daily weights which satisfy certain conditions
I have the following pandas dataframe which represents the consumption of 7 days (day_0 is today, day_-1 is yesterday etc) of 10 people (ids):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, 15, size=(10, 7)))
df.columns = ['day_0', 'day_-1', 'day_-2', 'day_-3', 'day_-4', 'day_-5', 'day_-6']
df.index.name = 'id'

print(df.reset_index())

   id  day_0  day_-1  day_-2  day_-3  day_-4  day_-5  day_-6
0   0    10      10      14       8      14      14      14
1   1    10      13      11      11       8      10      10
2   2    10      12       9      12       9      10      10
3   3    12      12       9      11       9      12      13
4   4    12      13       8      12       8      11       9
5   5    13       9       8      13       9      12      10
6   6     8       9       8      14       8      13      14
7   7    13      10      14      12       8       9      11
8   8     8       8      10      12      11      14      14
9   9    14      13      13       9      11      14      13

I would like to find daily weights (so in total 7 weights: w_0, w_-1, w_-2, w_-3, w_-4, w_-5, w_-6) which need to have the following properties:

w_0 > w_-1 > w_-2 > ... > w_-6 > 0
w_0 + w_-1 + w_-2 + ... + w_-6 = 7
the weighted average for exactly 7 out of 10 ids to be below a threshold (e.g. 11)

I can achieve prerequisites 1 & 2 by using the exponential decay function and later normalizing:
import numpy as np

n = 7

_lambda = 0.5

# Calculate the weights using exponential decay
weights = np.exp(-_lambda * np.arange(n))

# Normalize the weights so that their sum is equal to the length of the time series
weights *= n / np.sum(weights)

But I don't know how I could apply also prerequisite 3.
Is that possible? How can I do that in python?

Not sure I understand your constraints, maybe you want to start with condition 3, like generating random weights until they obey this condition. Then normalize them to comply with 2, finally sort them to satisfy your first predicate.

the weighted average for 7 out of 10 ids to be below a threshold needs a lot more definition. How do you define the ID subset? Do you mean that the threshold needs to be met for all possible subsets?

Or do you mean that the threshold needs to be met for at least one subset?

Also, are you sure about the > strictly decreasing requirement? If so, you need to choose some minimum value by which the weights must decrease. If not, switch to >=.

any 7 out of 10 ids will do

Yes, the weights should be strictly decreasing. The minimum value can be a very small number

This does not use exponential decay, because that doesn't seem particularly useful to meet your requirements. Define an ILP with a disjunction constraint that at exactly one combination of n out of m IDs has a weighted mean less than or equal to a threshold:
import io

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

with io.StringIO(
'''id,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6
    0, 10, 10, 14,  8, 14, 14, 14
    1, 10, 13, 11, 11,  8, 10, 10
    2, 10, 12,  9, 12,  9, 10, 10
    3, 12, 12,  9, 11,  9, 12, 13
    4, 12, 13,  8, 12,  8, 11,  9
    5, 13,  9,  8, 13,  9, 12, 10
    6,  8,  9,  8, 14,  8, 13, 14
    7, 13, 10, 14, 12,  8,  9, 11
    8,  8,  8, 10, 12, 11, 14, 14
    9, 14, 13, 13,  9, 11, 14, 13
''') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0)
df.columns = pd.Index(name='day', data=df.columns.astype(int))


m, n = df.shape  # number of IDs, days

'''
LP variables:
n weights
m weighted mean threshold binary predicates
'''

# The weight sum must be equal to n
sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.concatenate((
        np.ones(n), np.zeros(m),
    )),
    lb=n, ub=n,
)

# The weights must be strictly decreasing by this amount
min_decrease = 1e-2  # chosen fully arbitrarily
antimonotonic_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=scipy.sparse.diags_array(
        (
            np.ones(shape=n - 1),
            np.full(shape=n - 1, fill_value=-1),
        ),
        offsets=(0, 1), shape=(n - 1, n + m), format='csc',
    ),
    lb=min_decrease,
)

'''
For each binary threshold predicate,
pred = 1 iff weights.df_values/n <= threshold
lower bound:
pred >= 1 - (weights.values)/n/threshold
weights.values/threshold + pred*n >= n
upper bound:
pred <= 2 - (weights.values)/n/threshold
weights.values/threshold + pred*n <= 2*n
'''
threshold = 11
mean_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=scipy.sparse.hstack(
        (
            df.values/threshold,
            scipy.sparse.diags_array(
                np.full(shape=m, fill_value=n),
            ),
        ),
        format='csc',
    ),
    lb=n, ub=2*n,
)

# Exactly this many out of m IDs must be at the threshold or lower
n_up_to_threshold = 6
disjunction_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.concatenate((np.zeros(n), np.ones(m))),
    lb=n_up_to_threshold, ub=n_up_to_threshold,
)

result = milp(
    c=np.zeros(n + m),  # no optimisation objective
    integrality=np.concatenate((
        np.zeros(shape=n, dtype=np.uint8),  # weights are continuous
        np.ones(shape=m, dtype=np.uint8),   # predicates are binary
    )),
    bounds=Bounds(
        lb=np.concatenate((
            np.full(shape=n, fill_value=1e-2),  # minimum weight, arbitrary
            np.zeros(shape=m),  # binary predicate
        )),
        ub=np.concatenate((
            np.full(shape=n, fill_value=np.inf),
            np.ones(shape=m),  # binary predicate
        )),
    ),
    constraints=(
        sum_constraint,
        antimonotonic_constraint,
        mean_constraint,
        disjunction_constraint,
    ),
)
if not result.success:
    raise ValueError(result.message)

weights, threshold_preds = np.split(result.x, (n,))
means = df @ (weights/n)

print('weights =')
print(weights)
print('threshold predicates =')
print(threshold_preds)
print('means =')
print(means)

weights =
[2.96714286 1.01571429 1.00571429 0.99571429 0.98571429 0.02
 0.01      ]
threshold predicates =
[1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
means =
id
0    10.870612
1    10.439592
2    10.290204
3    11.005714
4    11.000000
5    11.130816
6     9.021429
7    11.847755
8     9.304490
9    12.576122
dtype: float64

Approximate solutions
To turn the hard threshold constraint into a soft constraint where the threshold moves to accommodate the input system,
import io

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

with io.StringIO(
'''id,  0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6
    0, 10, 10, 14,  8, 14, 14, 14
    1, 10, 13, 11, 11,  8, 10, 10
    2, 10, 12,  9, 12,  9, 10, 10
    3, 12, 12,  9, 11,  9, 12, 13
    4, 12, 13,  8, 12,  8, 11,  9
    5, 13,  9,  8, 13,  9, 12, 10
    6,  8,  9,  8, 14,  8, 13, 14
    7, 13, 10, 14, 12,  8,  9, 11
    8,  8,  8, 10, 12, 11, 14, 14
    9, 14, 13, 13,  9, 11, 14, 13
''') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0)
df.columns = pd.Index(name='day', data=df.columns.astype(int))


m, n = df.shape  # number of IDs, days

'''
LP variables:
n weights
m weighted mean threshold binary predicates
1 threshold
1 threshold error
'''

# The weight sum must be equal to n
sum_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.concatenate((
        np.ones(n),           # weights
        np.zeros(m + 1 + 1),  # preds, threshold, error
    )),
    lb=n, ub=n,
)

# The weights must be strictly decreasing by this amount
min_decrease = 1e-3  # chosen fully arbitrarily
antimonotonic_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=scipy.sparse.diags_array(
        (
            np.ones(shape=n - 1),                 # current weight
            np.full(shape=n - 1, fill_value=-1),  # next weight
        ),
        offsets=(0, 1),                # current and next weight index
        shape=(n - 1, n + m + 1 + 1),  # after the weight positions, everything is zero
        format='csc',
    ),
    lb=min_decrease,
)

'''
For each binary threshold predicate,
pred = 1 iff weights.df_values/n <= threshold
Upper bound (forces predicate to 0):
weights.df_values + pM - n*threshold <= M
Lower bound (forces predicate to 1):
weights.df_values + pM - n*threshold >= 0
'''
M = 2*df.sum(axis=1).max()
threshold_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=scipy.sparse.hstack(
        (
            df.values,                 # weights
            scipy.sparse.diags_array(  # predicates
                np.full(shape=m, fill_value=M),
            ),
            np.full(shape=(m, 1), fill_value=-n),  # threshold
            scipy.sparse.csc_array((m, 1)),        # error (0)
        ),
        format='csc',
    ),
    lb=0, ub=M,
)

# Exactly this many out of m IDs must be at the threshold or lower
n_up_to_threshold = 5
count_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.concatenate((
        np.zeros(n),      # weights
        np.ones(m),       # predicates
        np.zeros(1 + 1),  # threshold, error
    )),
    lb=n_up_to_threshold, ub=n_up_to_threshold,
)

'''
The absolute error must be relative to the threshold
error >= target - threshold    threshold + error >= target
error >= threshold - target    threshold - error <= target
'''
target_threshold = 12
error_constraint = LinearConstraint(
    A=scipy.sparse.hstack(
        (
            scipy.sparse.csc_array((2, n + m)),  # weights, predicates
            np.array((
                (1, +1),  # threshold, error
                (1, -1),
            )),
        ),
        format='csc',
    ),
    lb=(target_threshold, -np.inf),
    ub=(np.inf, target_threshold),
)

result = milp(
    c=np.concatenate((
        np.zeros(n + m + 1),  # weights, preds, threshold are non-optimised
        np.ones(1),           # threshold error is minimised
    )),
    integrality=np.concatenate((
        np.zeros(shape=n, dtype=np.uint8),  # weights are continuous
        np.ones(shape=m, dtype=np.uint8),   # predicates are binary
        (0, 0),                             # threshold, error are continuous
    )),
    bounds=Bounds(
        lb=np.concatenate((
            np.full(shape=n, fill_value=1e-3),  # minimum weight, arbitrary
            np.zeros(shape=m),                  # binary predicate
            (-np.inf, -np.inf),                 # threshold, error unbounded
        )),
        ub=np.concatenate((
            np.full(shape=n, fill_value=np.inf),  # weight unbounded
            np.ones(shape=m),                     # binary predicate
            (np.inf, np.inf),                     # threshold, error unbounded
        )),
    ),
    constraints=(
        sum_constraint,
        antimonotonic_constraint,
        threshold_constraint,
        count_constraint,
        error_constraint,
    ),
)
if not result.success:
    raise ValueError(result.message)

weights, preds, (threshold,), (error,) = np.split(result.x, (n, n+m, n+m+1))
means = df @ (weights/n)

print(f'threshold = {threshold:.3f}')
print(f'error from target of {target_threshold} = {error:.6f}')
print('weights =')
print(weights)
print('threshold predicates =')
print(preds)
print('means =')
print(means.values)

threshold = 11.996
error from target of 12 = 0.003857
weights =
[6.975e+00 1.000e-02 5.000e-03 4.000e-03 3.000e-03 2.000e-03 1.000e-03]
threshold predicates =
[1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
means =
[10.00514286 10.00471429 10.00285714 11.99614286 11.99614286 12.98828571
  8.00714286 12.99228571  8.00757143 13.99357143]


If I want 6 out of 10 IDs to be below the threshold, then I should change disjunction_constraint = LinearConstraint(     A=np.concatenate((np.zeros(n), np.ones(m))),     lb=n, ) to disjunction_constraint = LinearConstraint(     A=np.concatenate((np.zeros(n), np.ones(m))),     lb=6, ), right ?

but then if I do the above change, I get weights = [2.89083333 1.16833333 1.15833333 0.88125    0.87125    0.02  0.01      ] threshold predicates = [1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.] means = id 0    10.925119 1    10.543155 2    10.295655 3    11.005714 4    11.000000 5    11.000000 6     8.945119 7    11.902262 8     9.233631 9    12.663333 dtype: float64 which is the same result, except for the threshold_preds

@quant - because... You still need to be more specific. Do you mean exactly six, or at least six?

exactly 6. So there are 3 constrains in total. 1. The sum of weights to be exactly equal to the number of days (m). 2. Each weight should be strictly larger than the next one (all weights should be strictly larger than 0). 3. For exactly k out of n IDs,  their weighted average to be larger or equal to the threshold

Larger, really? You said smaller before. Oh dear.

Sorry smaller :). I edited the question as well

In any case, if kIDs are smaller than the threshold, then n-k IDs, will be larger. But you are right, I meant smaller.

I tried ```k = 5
disjunction_constraint = LinearConstraint(
A=np.concatenate((np.zeros(n), np.ones(m))),
lb=k, ub=k
)but then I get the exact same results, except for the `threshold predicates`, weights =
[2.89083333 1.16833333 1.15833333 0.88125    0.87125    0.02
0.01      ]
threshold predicates =
[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
means =
id
0    10.925119
1    10.543155
2    10.295655
3    11.005714
4    11.000000
5    11.000000
6     8.945119
7    11.902262
8     9.233631
9    12.663333```

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
